# Navigate to a UIViewController from inside a SwiftUIView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `UIKit` app where I have a `SwiftUIView` hosted in a `UIHostingController`, in this SwiftUIView I have a `Button` which I would like to use to navigate to another `UIViewController` when tapped.

How can I navigate to a `UIViewController` from inside a SwiftUIView?

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // on tap, go to MyViewController
        }) {
            Text("Go to UIViewController")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: Showing Code for `Kyokook Hwang` (Option One).

### My ViewController

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 21))
        myLabel.text = "My Label"
        view.addSubview(myLabel)
    }
}
```

### Struct File:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyView>) -> MyViewController {
        let vc = MyViewController()
        return vc
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyView>) {
    }
}
```

### SwiftUI Code:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State var isShowingMyVC = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.isShowingMyVC = true
            }) {
                Text("Go to UIViewController")
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMyVC) {
                    MyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are two way to achieve what you want to do.

**1. Use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.**

1) Create a bridge view with the protocol which embraces a UIViewController what you want to present.
2) Use `.sheet` operator to present the bridge view when the button is touched.

There is an example below.

```
struct MyView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyView>) -> MyViewController {
        let vc = MyViewController()
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyView>) {

    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var isShowingMyVC = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // on tap, go to MyViewController
            self.isShowingMyVC = true
        }) {
            Text("Go to UIViewController")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMyVC) {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Use a button action handler.**

If you don't want `SwiftUIView` to know any UIViewController that it should interact with, make `SwiftUIView` have an action handler which is called by the button. and then, use it somewhere in UIKit code in order to present any UIViewController.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var isShowingMyVC = false
    var tapHandler: (() -> Void)? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // on tap, go to MyViewController
            self.tapHandler?()
        }) {
            Text("Go to UIViewController")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMyVC) {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
let hostingView = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView() {
    self.present(MyViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
})
hostingView.view.frame = view.bounds
view.addSubview(hostingView.view)
```

I'm not sure of those two ways are exactly what you are looking for. Just hope it's useful to you.

Comment: I tried the first option and I got it to work but for some reason, I don't see the content in the `UIViewController`, all l see is a blank-white view that shows up modally, any idea what am I doing wrong? By the way, I really like that method, it's simple, hopefully, I can make it work.

Comment: Did you see the black-white view when you tried it with the first method? If you don't mind, I'd like to see your code little bit more to see what's wrong. @fs_tigre

Comment: I posted my code in the original question. Here is what I have noticed, the content in `MyViewController` is visible only if the content is presented in code, as shown in my code above, but my expectation was to be able to present an existing `UIViewController` done in a storyboard. In other words, the code I posted works just fine, I can see the `My Label` message but not the content that is directly in the storyboard. Is there any way to present the content in the storyboard or this only works with `UIViewControllers` written in code? Thanks!

Comment: You attached the label on runtime. In other words, it has been put on the screen by coding. It's not supposed to be shown on the storyboard that the VC is connected with. @fs_tigre

Comment: Any idea why it doesn’t show the content in the VC?